Delphi provisioning form for ad-hoc Win32 app code signing doesn't save settings
In Delphi 12.1, I created a VCL Win 32 app with a blank form, for testing signing in ad-hoc distribution.
Then I selected Project/Options, Deployment/Provisioning Build type: Windows 32-bit - Application Store, Distribution type: Ad hoc.
I created a self-signed certificate and filled in the Certificate file and Password fields.
This is the filled form:

Then, Save.
No error or warning messages are displayed.
But when I check again the provisioning form, filled data are lost,
I tried with different Target (Debug, Release, All), but I cannot save the page.
The Project/Deploy... menu entry is disabled, and the exe is not signed at all.

What's missing?
